# Sqoop from Hive table (avro format) date (or string) column to SQL Server date column?

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to sqoop from a Hive table (avro format) with a date (or string) column to a SQL Server table with date column ?

but I got :

Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

anyone know how to solve it ?

PS: I tried to add --map-column-hive column_name=date it does not help

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show the sqoop statement used and sample date in hive.
You can try  -D mapDateToTimestamp=false in sqoop statement